# Copy activity blob preserve metadata

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Using copy activity with Azure Data Factory to copy from blob storage to blob storage.  The metadata is not preserved when copying.  Have tried the preserve directive (see [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-preserve-metadata#preserve-metadata)) by editing the pipeline JSON definition without success.  No GUI support for preserving properties, tags or metadata with sinks + sources as blobs.  Ideas?

Here is an image of the Settings tab and a [gist](https://gist.github.com/MatthewDavidCampbell/9f31dab88c68e080e74390dbe331f37e) of the pipeline:

[image]

Comment: This option applies only to binary dataset because other types allow mapping, which can change contents, and make the metadata invalid.

Comment: When you select source and destination as binary file you will see this preserve option as [image](https://i.imgur.com/ArMz8Uy.png)

Comment: 2 comments.  Can you @PratikLad provide the JSON for the Copy activity?  And the image of the settings does not look like the Copy Data Activity in the Data Factory workspace in Azure.  The Settings tab for me with blob as sink and source has no Preserve.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier this option will enable only when you select both source and sink as binary file. [image](https://i.imgur.com/wBXtdOt.png)

Comment: @PratikLad Updated the gist with the Dataset JSON.  Everything was || is binary as Microsoft instructs in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-binary.  Both the sink + source use the same DataSet.  Would be helpful to see an example in JSON not from the GUI.

Comment: None of the 5 built-in system properties (content-type etc) are preserved (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-preserve-metadata#preserve-metadata).  Original content-type is "application/xml; charset=utf-8" and when copying it is "application/octet-stream".  The content-encoding is not transferred.  Only the md5 is the same.  Playing with the compression type has no effect.